# Having trouble accessing Twitter API 1.1 instead of API 1.0 in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django, json, api, twitter

At the moment, the code which accesses Twitter is simple and performs a simple search

```
def parsetwitter():
    api = twitter.Api([KEY-HERE], [KEY-HERE], [KEY-HERE], [KEY-HERE])
    statuses = api.GetSearch('#king')
    for s in statuses:
        print s.text.encode("utf8")
    return statuses
```

Now I thought this was working fine, and I thought this was using API 1.1 as I was logging in using OAuth but when the API 1.0 blackout happened, this went down...

So I figure I need help in two areas.

A. How do I modify the current code to ensure it is using API 1.1?

B. I know the following method is guaranteed to use API 1.1 but I don't know how to login with OAuth using this method.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
>>> import twitter
>>> client = twitter.Api()
>>> latest_posts = client.GetUserTimeline("yourusername")
>>> print [s.text for s in latest_posts]
```

This is a sample using authentication:

```
>>> client = twitter.Api(username='yourusername', password='yourpassword')
>>> update = client.PostUpdate('The Twitter API is easy')
```

I will also give you a link for Python Library Documentation:

http://static.unto.net/python-twitter/0.5/doc/twitter.html

Comment: I don't believe that will work with API 1.1 as it require OAuth login.

Comment: Sorry, it will work fine, as does my code :P But the problem is that there is a transition to API 1.1 happening now. API 1.1 requires OAuth login, and API 1.0 is subject to intermittent blackouts just now.

Comment: ah, the username and password

Comment: But my code already does that, albeit just using the up-to-date OAuth method :P My question is concerning how I make sure I am using 1.1 API instead of the 1.0 API.

Comment: Maybe you should read the latest API and compare the deprecated functions on it